# Jssor slider for prestashop

Tags: slider, jssor

Is there any way to block onload captions animations in jssor slider for prestashop? There isn't any option for that, but maybe some functions?

Comment: What do you mean onload caption?

Comment: when u check my slider on this site: http://www.asiana.pl/ u can see that there are some animations for text, I'd like to load my text static without animations (just slide animation). Can't find option in presta to disable animations on text, so I'm looking for some function.

Comment: Sorry that I am not familiar with presta.

Comment: There are I suppose yours files so maybe you know how and where (which file) should I edit to block those animations?

Comment: You can remove `$CaptionSliderOptions` from js code to disable caption animation.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll check it later. edit: removing this variable helped.